# Crontab and Shell Script not Executing

Tags: command-line, scripts, resolution, cron

Anybody any suggestions on why my crontab and shell script is not running.

I have

`chmod +x` my shell script and added the following into `crontab -e`

```
*/5 * * * * bash cd /home/jclark/scrips/ipcheck/ && ./ipCheck.sh
```

ipCheck.sh then costits of the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://api.externalip.net/ip/ -o ipRecord.txt
```

Although it doesn't appear to be running?

Comment: Curious, what are you doing with ipRecord.txt?

Answer (score 2):

You can't run bash commands like that.  Bash expects a file (a shell script) .as its argument.

You *might* be able to run the desired command like this:

```
*/5 * * * * bash -c "cd /home/jclark/scrips/ipcheck/ && ./ipCheck.sh"
```

Note the `-c` and the quotes around the commands you want to execute.

I think that what you actually want is:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/jclark/scrips/ipcheck/ipCheck.sh
```

... and the script should contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://api.externalip.net/ip/ -o /home/jclark/scripts/ipcheck/ipRecord.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the damn thing still doesn't seem to run!

Comment: @JacobClark Works for me on Ubuntu 12.10 exactly as I wrote it after the "what you actually want" part.

Comment: by running crontab -e?

Comment: @JacobClark Yep `crontab -e` is how I edited the crontab.  I added it to the crontab, waited till the clock hit the right time, then checked and saw that the file was updated.  Note that if you edit your crontab only a minute or two before it's supposed to trigger a job, the job probably won't be triggered.  Wait another 5 minutes.

Comment: I have done exactly has shown but my Ubuntu 12.04 Rackspace Cloud Server just isn't running it

Comment: Are you sure crond is running? `ps aux | grep crond | grep -v grep`

Comment: I would use `pgrep crond`